# Talend - Insert data into DB using Django REST API

Tags: talend

I am trying utilise Django REST APIs to insert data into the database, instead of the direct write. I've been able to read JSON data using the tRESTClient component but I am not too sure about the insertion/POST. Could someone point me to the components (and relation) that I should use?

The current job that I have is mostly:

```
Read data from raw file -> tMap -> DB
```

and I wish to do something like:

```
Read data from raw file -> tMap -> (pass on data to REST endpoint via POST)
```

Used the tRestClient component after my tMap and I could see the records getting inserted into the DB but all of them are without any data. Strangely nowhere I was asked to specify the JASON tree. The number of records getting inserted are equal to rows being read from raw file so at least something is right. But I couldn't locate the menu/options to specify which data element read from the raw file should tag to which JASON element.

How do I specify the data to JSON mapping?

PS: I realise that this might not be the most efficient way to ingest data but that's what the business wants since it brings in an additional layer of control.

Comment: >How do I specify the data to JSON mapping?

Have you tried tWriteJSONField?

Comment: I did. However, from the looks of it, the tRESTClient should be able to handle this use case. I need the data at the output of tMap to be sent over to the REST endpoint. With tWriteFileJSON, I was able to create a JSON file. I still don't understand how to use the iRESTClient to utilize that JSON file (or direct input from the tMap component). Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Not tWriteFileJSON, tWriteJSONField is a processor component (like tMap), and on output of it you might configure a json from input row. Add tWriteJSONField to your job, select it, press F1 and check documentation in studio

Comment: So your recommendation is to insert tWriteJSONField after tMap and then pass it on to tRESTClient?

Comment: If your rest service require JSON in body - it might help